# Should url of Ajax's $.post match url in the web.xml

Tags: java, jquery, json, servlets

I am trying to send data from js to a servlet.

my js is in webapp\secure folder while the servlet s in java\com\ servlet folder.

I read for sending data using ajax I use

```
$.post("someservletname", {cityName:"hello"});
```

In the web.xml

```
       <servlet>
            <servlet-name>someservletname</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>java.com.someservletname</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>someservletname</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/someservletname</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
```

But when i put a simple sysout.print statement I do not see anything. How do i make sure that the mapping worked properly.Should i give the complete url in the post function call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you put in the URL:

- context path of your web application

Regards
Philippe

Comment: Thank you... I had issues with the url sent via ajax to the servlet, it was missing the context path....